# How much late spring cold have damaged my walnuts

Tags: diagnosis, cold-weather, walnut

Unfortunately, last night temperature in my garden in Avenliq. East Azerbaijan of Iran country dropped to -3°C and these are my walnut new sprouts after that.
[image]
[image]

will these bear any fruit?

should I do something?(for example cutting darkened new growth)[image]

Comment: It is difficult to answer. Just wait. But what are your worries? (which kind of "damages" are you asking) Dead plant? Permanent damages? Less walnuts this year? late fruiting?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I don't think there would be permanent damages. damages maybe having less fruit or no fruit for this year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My trees grow new leafs but there is almost no fruit on them.